Why is positive definite defined this way?
Norm: A norm on a vector space $V$ is a function $\| \cdot \| : V \to \mathbb R$ which assigns each vector $x$ its length $\|x\| \in \mathbb R,$ such that for all $\lambda \in R$ and $x, y \in V$ the following holds: $\|\lambda x\|=\lambda \|x\|.$
Positive definite: $\|x\| \geq 0$, and $\|x\| = 0\iff x =$ zero vector
Why do we have to include the first operand if it's obvious that when $\|x\| = 0$, $x$ is the zero vector?

How can it be "obvious"? This is true because it is part of the definition, it doesn't follow from the other properties. Don't make the way you maybe intuitively think of "length" confuse you.

why do we need to include that property? My analogy to what it's saying is x >= 0 and x = 0, then x = 0.

@nameless___ You have your directions mixed up. $x = 0$ implies $\Vert x\Vert = 0$ since $\Vert x \Vert = \Vert 0 \cdot x \Vert = 0 \Vert x \Vert = 0$. The other direction, namely that the zero vector is the only vector whose norm is 0 is what the condition is there for.

Less confusing to phrase it in two parts: (i) $|x|\ge 0$ and (ii) $|x|=0 \Longleftrightarrow x=0$.

Btw you might want to think about (the mistake) $\Vert\lambda x\Vert = \lambda \Vert x\Vert$ a bit more.

-1 Carelessness with ‘$x\in R$,’ etc. Or fake.

There is nothing obvious about a definition. In my opinion it's a mistake from whoever wrote what you copied to write "assigns each vector $x$ its length". In an arbitrary vector space there is no "length". Of course in many cases (like the Euclidean space and many others) there is a more or less natural notion of length that can be used. But the point is that  you have a vector space $V$, and you assign a norm.
To (hopefully) clarify what I say, let us write the exact same definition with a slightly different notation:

Let $V$ be a real  vector space. A norm on $V$ is a function $g:V\to \mathbb R$ such that

$g(x)\geq0$ for all $x\in V$;
$g(x)=0\iff x=0$
$g(\lambda x)=|\lambda|\,g(x)$ for all $x\in V$, $\lambda\in\mathbb R$ (homogeneity);
$g(x+y)\leq g(x)+g(y)$ for al $x,y\in V$ (triangle inequality).


Why would any of these properties be obvious for a function $g$? It is true that the third property (homogeneity) implies the reverse implication in the second one: for if $x=0$, then $g(x)=0g(x)=0$, where the first $0$ is  the scalar $0$ and the second one the vector $0$. But there is nothing obvious about $g(x)=0$ implying that $x=0$.
After we have a norm $g$, we may say that the "length" of $x$ is $g(x)$. But this is not a very good terminology because a norm can be arbitrary, and any nonzero vector space admits many many distinct norms.

Thank you! This makes so much more sense. I understood it as ($g(x) \geq 0$ and $g(x) = 0$) <-> $x = 0$.

Glad I could help! Please upvote when you can (I think you'll need a bit more reputation for that), not just my answer but any other than you find useful in this site.

Yea I tried upvoting, but I couldn't because I didn't have enough reputation.

No worries :) $ $

The nonnegativity, homogeneity and the triangle inequality do not give $$\|x\|=0\implies x=0\quad (*)$$ For example  when $X=\mathbb{R}^2$ and $\|(x_1,x_2)\|=|x_1|$ then the three properties hold but $\|(0,1)\|=0.$ More generally,  consider a linear noninjective operator $T:X\to X$ on a normed space $X.$ Introduce $\|x\|_1:=\|Tx\|.$ Then the three properties are satisfied for $\|\ \|_1$ but $(*)$ fails.
